# Rank Query Results - Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got the following query that searches my customer database and does so successfully:

```
SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE ((("customers"."first_name" IN ('John', 'Doe') OR "customers"."last_name" IN ('John', 'Doe')) OR "customers"."email" IN ('John', 'Doe')) OR "customers"."main_phone" IN ('John', 'Doe'))
```

The equivalent Rails query is:

```
array = ["John","Doe","111-111-1111"]

Customer.where(first_name: array).or(customers.where(last_name: array)).or(customers.where(email: array)).or(customers.where(main_phone: array))
```

This works fine, however I am wanting to rank the results. For example, if record # 1 matches for both first and last name, I want that record to display at the top of my results. How could I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-controls.html

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If I were you I would write it in raw sql in my question and add `sql` tag so smart sql guys could come and help me out :) And specify db you are using

Answer (score 1):

The combination of where and or actually create a single SQL query with no "precedence" of the results
You will have to
1. break it down to separate queries
2. for each record found, count in how many queries it was found
3. order your results by this counter in descending order

Here is some code (it can be prettier):

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    def self.relevance_search(query)
        matches = []
        matches << Customer.where(first_name: query)
        matches << Customer.where(last_name: query)
        matches << Customer.where(email: query)
        matches << Customer.where(main_phone: query)

        counter = {}
        matches.each do |match|
            match.each do |match_result|
                id = match_result.id
                if counter.key? id
                    counter[id] += 1
                else
                    counter[id] = 1
                end
            end
        end
        counter.map { |id, occurrences| { relevance: 100*(occurrences/4.0), customer: Customer.find(id) } }.sort_by { |r| r[:relevance] }.reverse!
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
Customer.relevance_search ["John", "Doe", "111-111-1111"]
```

The return value is and array ordered by relevance in %

Enjoy :)

Comment: @CannonMoyer, have you seen my answer?